# Where is the sigmoid derivative used in the backpropagation algorithm and how are weights updated

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, backpropagation

I am a year 10 student trying to learn how a neural network works in python code. I don't have much calculus knowledge, only to the extent of a limited understanding of derivatives and how to find them.

I have made a simple feed-forward network in python using numpy. I have set up layer classes with a feed_forward function to matrix multiply the layer input with the layer weights and apply the sigmoid function to them to achieve an output which I understand is passed through to the next layer and so on through the network. I believe I have the correct knowledge with feedforward, but I don't understand how the error is backpropagated through the network and how the weights are then updated. Sources on the internet seem to dive into the calculus and then I lose alot of understanding.

This is my code currently:

```
class Layer:
    def __init__(self, neurons, connections, type):
        self.neurons = neurons
        self.weights = np.random.randn(neurons, connections)
        self.type = type
        self.learning_rate = .1

    def sigmoid(self, value):
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-value))

    def sigmoid_derr(self, value):
        return value * (1.0 - value)

    def feed_forward(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(input, self.weights))
        return self.output
```

```
 l1.feed_forward([0.15, 0.895])
 l2.feed_forward(l1.output)
 l3.feed_forward(l2.output)
```

I have tried calculating the error after the feedforward and applying squared error to it and backpropagating it back through the network similar to feedforward but backwards through the network using transposed weights. I then attempted to multiply the output at each layer by two as is the derivative and adding that derived error to the weights by each neurons connection. However, as I iterated through the output just approached one. All help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I found a video on youtube that somewhat explains what i am trying to achieve and i have tried to implement it myself however, on some runs the network tries to get itself as close to 0.519 as possible. I am not sure why.
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np

INPUT = 'INPUT'
HIDDEN = 'HIDDEN'
OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'


class Layer:
    def __init__(self, neurons, connections, type):
        self.neurons = neurons
        self.weights = np.random.randn(neurons, connections)
        self.type = type
        self.learning_rate = .1

    def sigmoid(self, value):
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-value))

    def sigmoid_derr(self, value):
        return value * (1-value)
        #return self.sigmoid(value) * (1.0 - self.sigmoid(value))

    def cost_derivative(self, expected, actual):
        return np.multiply(np.power(np.subtract(expected, actual),2),2)

    def feed_forward(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(input, self.weights))
        return self.output

    def backprop(self, expected=[], prevError=None):  # fowardLayerWeights is the previous backpropagated layers weights
        if self.type == OUTPUT:
            self.error = np.subtract(expected, self.output)
            self.delta = np.multiply(self.error, self.sigmoid_derr(self.output))

            self.error = np.dot(self.error, self.weights.T)
        else:
            self.delta = np.multiply(prevError, self.sigmoid_derr(self.output))
            self.error = np.dot(prevError, self.weights.T)



l1 = Layer(2, 3, type=INPUT)
l2 = Layer(3, 4, type=HIDDEN)
l3 = Layer(4, 2, type=OUTPUT)

for i in range(10000):
    l1.feed_forward([0.26, 0.87])
    l2.feed_forward(l1.output)
    l3.feed_forward(l2.output)

    l3.backprop(expected=[0.12, 0.92])
    l2.backprop(prevError=l3.error)
    l1.backprop(prevError=l2.error)

    #print(l3.output)

    l3.weights += np.dot(l3.output.T, l3.delta)
    l2.weights += np.dot(l2.output.T, l2.delta)
    l1.weights += np.dot(l1.output.T, l1.delta)

    print(l3.output)
```

This is the video if you want it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3l4qz76JhQ

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your backprop is the `sigmoid_derr` function, but the implementation is not right for the derivative of the sigmoid.

S`(x) = S(x)[1-S(x)]

Where S(x) is the sigmoid derivation. Check [this link](https://beckernick.github.io/sigmoid-derivative-neural-network/) for more.

Comment: It is like that because the values i am passing into the function have already been put through sigmoid. Other sources that i have looked at seem to use this implementation. Am i supposed to put it through sigmoid again?

Comment: Try it on a piece of paper. The derivative won't come out the same...